# Benchmark /dev/shm

Tags: linux, io, ram, benchmark, ramdisk

I am currently developing a software that needs fast inter-process and temporary I/O communication (images as well as big hdf5 arrays). The "lifetime" of the data is different and dependent on several things, but in most cases something between seconds to minutes. Only a few files have to be stored longer. None of the data needs to be saved persistently.

Hence, I thought `/dev/shm` should be the way to go. However, I am struggling to benchmark `/dev/shm`.

My first attempt was:

```
sudo dd if=/proc/kcore of=/dev/shm/mem count=1000000
```

...which shows the following result:

```
1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
512000000 bytes (512 MB, 488 MiB) copied, 0,661147 s, 774 MB/s
```

However, when I run `dd` with the `bs` flag to specify how many bytes have to be read/written at a time, the result heavily changes:

```
sudo dd if=/proc/kcore of=/dev/shm/mem bs=$((1024*1024)) count=512
```

...results in:

```
512+0 records in
512+0 records out
536870912 bytes (537 MB, 512 MiB) copied, 0,166003 s, 3,2 GB/s
```

---

Why is it so much faster to read/write very big chunks of data (many bytes 512 times) compared to small chunks of data a lot of times (1.000.000 times, like in the first attempt)?

Is it "legit" to benchmark `/dev/shm` with `dd` using `/proc/kcore` as the source? Or is `/proc/kcore` somehow limiting the benchmark?

I can not exactly tell how much performance I *really* do need, but I would like to have more than 1 GB/s read & write speed (because the largest amount of data I am reading or writing is 1 GB and I would like to do so in less than a second).

---

I am mostly storing big arrays (50 MB up to 1 GB) via [HDF5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format).

Comment: Is your software actually using `dd` for `IPC`?

Comment: No, not at all. I just thought `dd` is an intuitive way to benchmark `/dev/shm`. Does it matter if data is written via `dd` or over tools? I mainly store big arrays with hdf5.